# How to use custom torch.autograd.Function in nn.Sequential model

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

Is there any way that I can use custom `torch.autograd.Function` in a `nn.Sequential` object or should I use explicitly an `nn.Module` object with forward function. Specifically I am trying to implement a sparse autoencoder and I need to add L1 distance of the code(hidden representation) to the loss.
I have defined custom `torch.autograd.Function` L1Penalty below then tried to use it inside a `nn.Sequential` object as below. However when I run I got the error `TypeError: __main__.L1Penalty is not a Module subclass` How can I solve this issue?

```
class L1Penalty(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input, l1weight = 0.1):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        ctx.l1weight = l1weight
        return input, None

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_variables
        grad_input = input.clone().sign().mul(ctx.l1weight)
        grad_input+=grad_output
        return grad_input
```

```
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(10, 10),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(10, 6),
    nn.ReLU(),
    # sparsity
    L1Penalty(),
    nn.Linear(6, 10),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(10, 10),
    nn.ReLU()
).to(device)
```

Comment: Any code to share?

Comment: Sure, I have edited question.

Comment: so as I see it, you want to use it like an identity function in forward mode and want to multiply the gradient by a factor(0.1) in the backward mode. Is that correct?

Comment: Your autograd function also seems to be incorrect:

`a = torch.rand(50,10);
f = L1Penalty();
b = f(a) 
`
This gives `TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input'`. This might be the actual cause of your error

Comment: @PiyushSingh in the forward mode I want identity as you mention, but in the backward mode I want to add 0.1*(activation at that layer) to the gradient. Also, when you call function as f.apply(a), it works. However, maybe when I instantiate function that way; by default pytorch call it as you have done. Yet our error messages are different.

Comment: Have added my answer. (works) @akurmustafa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do that would be this

```py
import torch, torch.nn as nn

class L1Penalty(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input, l1weight = 0.1):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        ctx.l1weight = l1weight
        return input

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_variables
        grad_input = input.clone().sign().mul(ctx.l1weight)
        grad_input+=grad_output
        return grad_input
```

Creating a Lambda class that acts as a wrapper

```py
class Lambda(nn.Module):
    """
    Input: A Function
    Returns : A Module that can be used
        inside nn.Sequential
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func

    def forward(self, x): return self.func(x)
```

TA-DA!

```py
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(10, 10),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(10, 6),
    nn.ReLU(),
    # sparsity
    Lambda(L1Penalty.apply),
    nn.Linear(6, 10),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(10, 10),
    nn.ReLU())

a = torch.rand(50,10)
b = model(a)
print(b.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nn.Module` API seems to work fine but you should not return None in your `L1Penalty` `forward` method.

```
import torch, torch.nn as nn

class L1Penalty(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input, l1weight = 0.1):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        ctx.l1weight = l1weight
        return input

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_variables
        grad_input = input.clone().sign().mul(ctx.l1weight)
        grad_input+=grad_output
        return grad_input


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10,10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10,6)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(6,10)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(10,10)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.penalty = L1Penalty()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.penalty.apply(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x


model = Model()
a = torch.rand(50,10)
b = model(a)
print(b.shape)
```

Comment: I think second return of the L1Penalty required in the backward mode. I tried to write using nn.Sequential, but you version works now. Thanks.